# "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here."

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

Around 12 hours ago, I tried creating a personal blog using '[beautiful jekyll](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll)'. I followed the simplest 3-step method to get a basic blog running however, every time I enter my website link, I get

> There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.
>
> If you're trying to publish one, read the full documentation to learn
>   how to set up GitHub Pages for your repository, organization, or user
>   account.

There isn't anything that I did different from the tutorial. I want to know does github just takes long to publish the pages or is there some sorcery ?

Comment: Is your repo named after your GitHub username account? `<username>.github.io`

Comment: Please tell us where your repo is and what url you tried.

Comment: @JoostS: Here is the url to my repo [is here](https://github.com/nitinrabbit/yourboygorja.github.io). The url to [my blog](http://yourboygorja.github.io).

Comment: @VonC: Yes it is named the same.

Comment: https://github.com/nitinrabbit/yourboygorja.github.io would not work, since yourboygorja is *not* your GitHub username. nitinrabbit is. So the repo should be called https://github.com/nitinrabbit/nitinrabbit.github.io

Comment: @VonC: Blunder accepted, thanks a lot !

Comment: OK I will post an answer later today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I commented:

github.com/nitinrabbit/yourboygorja.github.io would not work, since `yourboygorja` is *not* your GitHub username. `nitinrabbit` is.

So the repo should be called `github.com/nitinrabbit/nitinrabbit.github.io`

And some content needs to be pushed to it.

Comment: while mine is already correct which gave me a deeper confusion right now

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go to the settings>pages>Source>Main (or subfolders) to activate page root. You may find detailed explanations here.

https://hackernoon.com/use-custom-domain-with-github-pages-2-straightforward-steps-cf561eee244f